# Confusing Python Function! Looks simple but answer is not what I expected

Tags: python-3.x, function

```
def f(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    return x + f(x - 1)

print(f(3))
```

I looked at this and though the answer would be 5, but it works out as 6.
If x = 3, then x - 1 should be 2, added together then should be 5... so how does it come up with 6?

Comment: Because it's not just `3 + 2`, it's `3 + 2 + 1 + 0`.Try running it through e.g. http://www.pythontutor.com/ and read up on *"recursion"*.

Comment: That website is brilliant!  That will be my 'goto' place in future before I ask any more n00b questions on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `f(3)`, it will recursively run `f(2)`. In turn, `f(2)` recursively runs `f(1)` and finally `f(1)` runs `f(0)`. At this point, `f(0)` returns 0, so `f(1)` returns `1 + 0 = 0`, `f(2)` returns `2 + 1 = 3` and `f(3)` returns `3 + 3 = 6`.

Comment: So when it reaches the 'base state' (?) of zero, this prevents an endless cycle?

Comment: when it reaches `f(0)`, then the `if` statement is satisfied. No more function calls are executed and instead `0` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot f(1).

```
f(3) = 3 + f(2)
f(3) = 3 + 2 + f(1)
f(3) = 3 + 2 + 1 + f(0)
f(3) = 3 + 2 + 1 + 0
f(3) = 6
```

The recursion will stop only if x == 0, not at the 2th call.
f(3) calls f(2) but f(2) calls f(1) and f(1) calls f(0).

Comment: Thank you.  I only just started to learn about recursive functions, that makes sense now.  Not easy at this stage to get my head around.

Comment: No problem. Recursive function is a function that call itself until the exit condition is reached. It stop at f(0) because you return the "end value" and it doesn't call f again

Comment: Here's a good tutorial I followed: https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/

Answer (score 0):

If you check each recursive call, you'd get something like

```
3+f(2)

3+2+f(1)

3+2+1+0 = 6
```

Comment: Presumably, I would have to use a debugger to check each recursive call?

Comment: a simple `print` statement will do